# Deploy to JBoss 7 using Hudson Deploy plugin

Tags: deployment, jboss, hudson

I have 2 machines where one of them contains the Hudson CI and other JBoss 7 AS. In Hudson, I have installed "Deploy Plugin", created new job and filled required JBoss manager user connection fields. When I run the job, the project successfully built however the deployment process to remote JBoss AS is not being triggered. No errors or messages about the deployment in log. What should I do?

**EDIT**
The deployment is triggered (at least expected) as "Post-build Action" with parameters:

```
[x] Deploy war/ear to a container  
WAR/EAR files              : **/*.war  
Container                  : JBoss 7.x  
Manager user name          : test  
Manager password           : * * * *
JBoss URL                  : http://192.168.1.2  
JBoss JMX Management port  : 9999
```

It is not a separate job.

Answer (score 0):

Please describe your job setup a bit more in detail, specifically how are you triggering the deploy as a post build step or triggering a dependent job?

If possible viewing the config.xml can help.

Comment: updated the question.

Comment: AS 7 has admin web and (I think) JMX interfaces locked down by default, so you might want to check on that part; other than that there is nothing that comes to my mind on possible causes

Comment: Ok I resolved it. The maven build was configured incorrectly. But I have another problem. The JBoss's management interface has `<inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.management:192.168.2.2}"/>`, so remote clients can access it. The problem is, `Could not connect to remote://192.168.2.2:9999. The connection failed` caused by `Authentication failed: all available authentication mechanisms failed` while trying to deploy. Have you any idea?

Comment: test is already added as "Manager User" to JBoss.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to create an user:

```
/path/to/jboss/bin/add-user.sh jbossAdministrator
```

Choose a, Management User, set the password and that's it. Use it on your hudson configuration. [Here](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/add-user+utility?_sscc=t) is the doc for add-user.sh on JBoss7